# Oops what does this mean in c?

Tags: c

```
if ( sscanf( line, "%[^ ] %[^ ] %[^ ]", method, url, protocol ) != 3 )...
```

That format above is very strange,what's it doing?

Comment: The `[` specification should have a fixed width to avoid buffer overflows: `... sscanf(line, "%19[^ ] %19[^ ] %19[^ ]", ...`, assuming arrays of 20 chars

Comment: @pmg: Put that as an answer, we will vote you up.

Comment: It's ok @Vlad: the comment upvotes are great too, thanks

Comment: @pmg ,this kind of format is `sscanf` only ,not available in printf,right?

Comment: @compile-fan: it works somewhat differently in `printf`. `printf("%.18s", astring)` prints the first 18 characters of `astring` if it is longer than that

Comment: @pmg,I mean this kinda regex format like `%[^ ]` doesn't exist for `printf`,right?

Comment: @compile: nope. If you want something like that you have to write your own (or use a library)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That line is attempting to read 3 strings that do not contain a space separated by spaces into method, url, protocol and if it fails to read 3 it will then enter the if block.

Comment: It uses 3 scansets each with %[^ ] the ^ means not the following characters and it is followed by a space. for instance %[^abc] will scan everything until an a,b, or c character is found. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html

Comment: Will it work for 3 strings separated by **more than one** spaces?

Comment: yes as long as there is no space before the first occurrence, try this example `const char *line = "post   google.com    http";
 char method[5], url[11], protocol[5];
 printf("%d %s %s://%s\n", sscanf(line, "%4[^ ] %10[^ ] %4[^ ]", method, url, protocol), method, protocol, url);` remember as pmg said above use a fixed width. The comments stripped the spaces but just add extra spaces between post google.com and http.

Answer (score 3):

the `[]` is the scanset. If you tell `%[abcd]` then an input string only with *a* or *b* or *c* or *d* will be considered. The string would terminate at the first occurance of some other character which is *not* any of the characters in the braces.

The `^` inside the `[]` is used to denote the compliment of the set inside the braces. Like with the format string `%[^abcd]` will only accept all characters *except* , *a* or *b* or *c* or *d*.

so in `%[^ ]` , the blankspace followed by the `^` tells that, the format string will accept *any* character combination in the string which *does not* have a blankspace.

The format string `"%[^ ] %[^ ] %[^ ]"` will match a string which has three components separated by blankspaces. Each of the component will contain a sequence of characters which have no space inside them.

The function returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

So the above function will return `3` only if and only if all the three components are read, that is, the input line has three partitions and for each partition the three arrays `method`, `url` and `protocol` was populated.

Answer (score 0):

[scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) is a function that reads data from a string and returns the number of items successfully read.

So, `scanf` will parse `line` to to find 3 string containing a space and separated by a space and will put these 3 strings in the 3 variables that follows (`method`, `url`, `protocol`).

Then if it has parsed 3 arguments, it'll enter the `if` block.